# Mysql how to get to list columns combined with other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot

I have a table like this

```
+------+------+----------+
| X    | Y    | SAMPLE_id |
+------+------+----------+
|  1.0 |   10 |        1 |
|  1.0 |   20 |        2 |
|  1.0 |   30 |        3 |
|  1.0 |   40 |        4 |
|  2.0 |   25 |        1 |
|  2.0 |   26 |        2 |
|  2.0 |   27 |        3 |
|  2.0 |   28 |        4 |
|  3.0 |   35 |        1 |
|  3.0 |   35 |        2 |
|  3.0 |   35 |        3 |
|  3.0 |   35 |        4 |
|  4.0 |   50 |        1 |
|  4.0 |   50 |        2 |
|  4.0 |   50 |        3 |
|  4.0 |   50 |        4 |
|  5.0 |   65 |        1 |
|  5.0 |   65 |        2 |
|  5.0 |   65 |        3 |
|  5.0 |   65 |        4 |
```

**I need to display like this **

```
X  Y_SAMPLE_ID_1 Y_SAMPLE_ID_2 Y_SAMPLE_ID_3 Y_SAMPLE_ID_4
1 10             20            30            40  
2 25             26            27            28
...
..
..
```

Though I have tried various options resulted in errors, I could not get as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fixed list of sample ids, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    x,
    max(case when sample_id = 1 then y end) y_sample_id_1,
    max(case when sample_id = 2 then y end) y_sample_id_2,
    max(case when sample_id = 3 then y end) y_sample_id_3,
    max(case when sample_id = 4 then y end) y_sample_id_4
from mytable
group by x
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks, Any explanation of the commands will be useful for many

Comment: @vkkindia: the query aggregates by `x`; then, each `max(...)` expression acquires the value of `y` for each distinct `sample_id`.